# mysql get rows between two dates based on two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

My table have structure like this

```
id | date_birth | date_marriage
1  | 1970-01-24 | 2000-05-14
2  | 1979-05-08 | 2008-08-12
```

How to get events between two dates for above data in mysql (date comparison is irrespective of year) . For example if start_date is 2014-05-01 and end date is 2014-05-20 then output should be

```
id | event
1  | married on 2000-05-14
2  | born on 1979-05-08
```

UPDATE:
If both  date of marriage and birth date falls in the supplied date range for same person the output should contains two columns for the person

( sorry for my bad english )

Comment: Can you prepare SQLfiddle?

Comment: @user4035 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11286

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to your comment, you can get two rows if either date matches by using a `union`.

You can check the date regardless of year by converting to a format that does not include the year, for example `%m%d`.  Note that the format should be sortable (most significant number first) for the comparison to work.

```
select  *
from    YourTable
where   date_format(date_birth,'%m%d') between '0501' and '0520'
union all
select  *
from    YourTable
where   date_format(date_marriage,'%m%d') between '0501' and '0520'
```

Comment: What if date of birth and date of marriage falls in same month? I want it as two rows then